# Не накапливаться значение jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте вот такая проблема, нужно при нажатии на крестик накапливать значение, но при нажатии на крестик он обновляется и выбираться новый
Вот код
https://jsfiddle.net/pbg7sjv1/ обработчик на 649 строке

вот он

```
else {// Резюмируем дневные действия
    $die=$boom=$foul=0;
    $('.tr').each(function(){
        // Определяем ID строки (игрока)
        arr=$regRowID.exec($(this).attr('id'));
        if (0!=arr[1]){
            s='';
            // Теперь проверяем все кнопки, которые есть у игрока
            $(this).find(":button").each(function(){

                // Если кнопка отмечена, как нажатая, то обрабатываем
                if ($(this).hasClass($classBtnSelected)) {

                        console.log(s);
                    // Если казнён, запоминаем это
                    if ($arBtnTitles[7]==$(this).val()) {
                        $die=arr[1];
                        //s+=$(this).val();
                    }
                    // Если взорван, запоминаем это
                    if ($arBtnTitles[8]==$(this).val()){
                        $boom=arr[1];
                        //s+=$(this).val();
                    }
                    // Если игрок получил замечание, запоминаем это и добавляем метку фола
                    if ($arBtnTitles[9]==$(this).val()) {
                        $foul=arr[1];
                        $('#foul'+arr[1]).html($('#foul'+arr[1]).html()+$arBtnTitles[9]);
                    }
                    // Накапливаем значения кнопок, кроме фолов
                    if ($arBtnTitles[9]!=$(this).val())
                        s+=$(this).val();
                }
                $('#actg'+arr[1]+'st'+State+'r'+$round).html(s);
            });

        }
    });
```

Почему-то обычное накапливание через s+=$(this).val(); не работает

Comment: Если не обращать внимания на теги, можно подумать что это php

Comment: не это js + jquery

Comment: может s='';  повыше перенести?

Comment: @BearVorkuta поменялось что-то но не помогло≤ также попробовал убрать, тоже не то

Comment: Скорее всего, не выполняется условие `if ($arBtnTitles[9]!=$(this).val())`

Comment: @fixer попробовал удалить, всё равно не работает

Comment: Оно просто не делает мульчи выбор, а это уже идёт как вывод значений